# Python 3, замена участков html кода и сохранения результата в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

В html коде нужно заменить три разных участка в коде и потом сохранить изменённый результат в html файл. Как один раз заменить, разобрался. Но возникли проблемы, как проделать эту процедуру второй и третий раз в html коде который я уже заменил один раз после чего сохранить данный в файл для дальнейшего парсинга.

```
# импортируем библиотеки
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# извлекаем данные
response = requests.get('https://site.com')
# декодируем в utf-8
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
# декодируем байты в строку
response.text

# заменяем код 
html_code = response.text.__str__().replace('Title</h3><div class="block">', 'Title</h3><div class="block_my_1"')
```

Comment: `.replace('a', 'b').replace('c', 'd').replace('e', 'f')` ?)

Comment: @Violet Спасибо, работает и понял как мне информацию искать в дальнейшем, чтобы по снизить количество вопросов.